# How to boot in vmware?

Tags: assembly, kernel, vmware, nasm, boot

I came across these two lines in osdev wiki.

```
 nasm kernel.asm -f bin -o kernel.bin
    dd if=kernel.bin of=/dev/fd0
```

It copies the kernel binary to a flopy. Does this means the flopy becomes bootable? I don't want to create a bootable flopy , instead of that I want to create a iso image by which I can boot in vmware. is it possible? If possible , how to do it? Kindly explain with description. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am desperately waiting for answer. Help please.

Comment: I think you should provide much more detail, like what you intend to do and maybe the source code for kernel.asm

Answer (score 0):

Kernel.bin is a bootloader, and the first sector of a 1.44mb floppy disk is the boot sector.

So when you write (using dd in this case) it serially writes the data to the first sector onwards.

From my experience, look up qEmu. I don't have it to hand, but you can boot bootloaders using that perfectly without converting to img or iso.

Answer (score 0):

After you've run the above code, you can simply use the command below to create an image of your floppy disk,

```
dd if=/dev/fd0 of=Image.img
```

(do it as root)

You should be able to boot from the Image.img using a virtual machine.